# Displaying a route from current location to destination location without launching any url in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I had used following code in my app but it opens new window and shows route fromcurrent location to destination.

code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps?       daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f",12.8400,77.6700, 12.9610850,77.604692699999990];

NSString *escapedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

but my requirement is to show route from current location to destination location without launching any url.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request a directions for example from Google

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true&mode=%@&departure_time=%ld
```

And then get the routes from received json and write the path on the map.

Comment: Just want to add onto nerowolfe's answer. Google Direction's API returns you JSON result and part of that results include the base64 encoded polyline which you need to decode. You also get the text direction such as "turn left at XYZ street, drive for 300 metres.." etc. Other things include number of legs and steps inside the JSON. Note, Google agreement their API only useable on Google-maps, and not allowed on non-google maps. In that case, you might be able to use Google's Map Framework thing or you can set your target iOS to 5.0 which is last Google map iOS version :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a WebView and load that url in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `UIWebView` and load the above `URL`  in it

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps? daddr=%f,%f&saddr=%f,%f",12.8400,77.6700, 12.9610850,77.604692699999990];

NSString *escapedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
[webveiew loadRequest : [NSURLRequest requestwithURL:url]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use google maps api. Go through their documentation. Its helpful. I had used it in my application.